# Timeout expired in sql server problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic, ado

```
set con2=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con2.ConnectionTimeout =1200
con2.open "Driver={SQL Server};server=111.111.111.11;user id=xx;pwd=xxx;Database=xxx"
con2.execute("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE fieldid NOT IN(SELECT fieldid FROM tablename2)")
con2.close
set con2=nothing
```

when i running this query using asp the following error occured. How to solve this issue?

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers error '80040e31'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Timeout expired

Comment: How long does it take when you run just the SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: 1 minutes and 24 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `not in`, use a `left join`:

```
delete from tablename
left join tablename2 on tablename2.fieldid = tablename.fieldid
where tablename2.fieldid is null
```